# What is the difference between pointer::swap() and std::ptr::swap()?

Tags: pointers, rust

What's the difference between pointer's method [`swap()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.pointer.html#method.swap) and [`std::ptr::swap()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/fn.swap.html) ?

The signatures are similar, and they behaves the same as far as I tested.

```rust
pub unsafe fn swap(self, with: *mut T)
```

```rust
pub unsafe fn swap<T>(x: *mut T, y: *mut T)
```

As for `std::mem::swap()` (for reference rather than pointer), there is a situation where we cannot call `std::mem::swap()` as it needs two mutable references. In that case, we shall call `slice::swap()` for example. What about `std::ptr::swap()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference between `ptr.swap()` and `std::ptr::swap()` - [the former's implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/ptr/mut_ptr.rs.html#1526-1528) just calls into the latter:

```rust
pub const unsafe fn swap(self, with: *mut T)
where
    T: Sized,
{
    // SAFETY: the caller must uphold the safety contract for `swap`.
    unsafe { swap(self, with) }
}
```

---

As per [the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/fn.swap.html), the only differences between `mem::swap` and `ptr::swap` are:

- `ptr::swap` operates on pointers instead of references.
- `ptr::swap` allows the pointed-to values to overlap.
- `ptr::swap` does not require the pointed-to data to be initialized/meet the requirements for the pointed-to type.

Other than that, their semantics are the same.

Comment: Do you know why `std::ptr::swap()` exists in the first place? It seems `ptr.swap()` is enough (while both `std::mem::swap()` and `slice.swap()` have to exist for reference). Maybe just for historial reason, as the former is available since 1.0.0 and the latter since 1.26.0?

Comment: `std::ptr::swap` has existed since Rust 1.0, while `ptr.swap()` wasn't added until Rust 1.26 - I'm not sure if this was due to a technical limitation or if it just wasn't thought of until later.

Comment: @ynn [Here's the RFC](https://github.com/Gankra/rfcs/blob/sharpie/text/0000-unsafe-pointer-reform.md). Specifically, the motivation: "Swift lets you do this: `...` And we want to be cool like Swift, right?". A nice motivation.